# Binding properties (width/sorting) of DataGrid on dynamic TabPage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, tabcontrol

I've created a little wpf test project to demonstrate my question. This project contains a single wpf window. This window contains only a `TabControl`. The pages of this `TabControl` are created dynamically from the bound `ItemSource`.

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestWpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource ="{Binding MediaLists, ElementName=window, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MediaList}">
                <TextBlock Padding="2" Text="{Binding MediaTypeName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="contentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:MediaList}">
                <DataGrid x:Name="dgMediaList" ItemsSource="{Binding Medias, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="clmAuthor" Header="Author" Binding="{Binding Author}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorder="False" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="clmTitle" Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorder="False" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

And the code behind is like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<MediaList> m_MediaLists = new ObservableCollection<MediaList>();
    public ObservableCollection<MediaList> MediaLists { get { return m_MediaLists; } } 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MediaList cdList = new MediaList("CDs");
        cdList.Medias.Add(new Media("AuthorCdA", "TitleCdA1"));
        cdList.Medias.Add(new Media("AuthorCdA", "TitleCdA2"));
        cdList.Medias.Add(new Media("AuthorCdB", "TitleCdB1"));
        cdList.Medias.Add(new Media("AuthorCdB", "TitleCdB2"));

        MediaList bookList = new MediaList("Books");
        bookList.Medias.Add(new Media("AuthorBookA", "TitleBookA1"));
        bookList.Medias.Add(new Media("AuthorBookA", "TitleBookA2"));
        bookList.Medias.Add(new Media("AuthorBookB", "TitleBookB1"));
        bookList.Medias.Add(new Media("AuthorBookB", "TitleBookB2"));

        m_MediaLists.Add(cdList);
        m_MediaLists.Add(bookList);
    }
}
```

With `MediaList` as this:

```
public class MediaList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private readonly ObservableCollection<Media> m_Medias = new ObservableCollection<Media>(); 
    public string MediaTypeName { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Media> Medias { get { return m_Medias; }}

    public MediaList(string typeName)
    {
        MediaTypeName = typeName;
    }
}
```

And `Media` like this:

```
public class Media
{
    public string Author { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public Media(string author, string title)
    {
        Author = author;
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

So this all works fine as you can see here:

[image]

Now the problem: is **how to save the `DataGrid`'s layout for each `TabPage`?** When I switch between the `TabPage`s, the column width are kept the same for all pages, but the sorting is always lost completely.

I want to bind the column widths of the `DataGrid` as well as the **multi-column** sort settings as changed by the user in members of the `MediaList` instance.

So to keep this question short, let's concentrate on the column widths. I added the members to the `MediaList` class:

```
private DataGridLength m_WidthAuthor = DataGridLength.SizeToCells;
private DataGridLength m_WidthTitle = DataGridLength.SizeToCells;
public DataGridLength WidthAuthor
{
    get { return m_WidthAuthor; }
    set
    {
        if (value == m_WidthAuthor) return;
        m_WidthAuthor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("WidthAuthor");
    }
}
public DataGridLength WidthTitle
{
    get { return m_WidthTitle; }
    set
    {
        if (value == m_WidthTitle) return;
        m_WidthTitle = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("WidthTitle");
    }
}
```

and tried to set the binding in the xaml:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="clmAuthor" ... Width="{Binding WidthAuthor, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="clmTitle" ... Width="{Binding WidthTitle, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

But unfortunatly, this doesn't work. I've read on several SO articles that a two-way binding would be difficult. But even one-way binding won't work for me. (*I'm pretty new to wpf/mvvm, so maybe I use some wrong words here...*)

In the debugger output window I can see these error message for my width-bindings:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=WidthAuthor; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=54916642); target property is 'Width' (type 'DataGridLength')
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=WidthTitle; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=40809782); target property is 'Width' (type 'DataGridLength')
```

So if anyone can tell me how to save those `DataGrid` properties for each `TabPage` I would be very happy. Focus of this question is on the widths. The sorting may be subject of a new question (note that binding the `SortDirection` of the columns probably won't work for multi-column sort)

**EDIT:** I've added `diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to the `Binding` expression to one of the columns `Width` and found these messages in the debug output:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=18270086): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn.Width (hash=37671782)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 64 : BindingExpression (hash=18270086): Use Framework mentor <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=18270086): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=18270086): Framework mentor not found
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=18270086): Resolve source deferred
```

I'm too new to wpf to understand what that `Framework mentor` is and if this should really be `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the help of [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/). Unfortunately my wpf knowledge is still so low that I cannot explain (as well as the author of the mentioned article) what happens behind the scenes and if this is really a good solution.

So here is what I did:

#### Implementing a `BindingProxy` inherited from `Freezable`

One of the problems is that the `DataContext` is not inherited to `DataGridTextColumn`. So the aim is to store it in a proxy.

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get { return GetValue(DATA_PROPERTY); }
        set { SetValue(DATA_PROPERTY, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DATA_PROPERTY =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

#### Declaring an instance of `BindingProxy` as local resource in `DataGrid`

I added this local resource to my `DataGrid` in xaml:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <vm:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

#### Adjusting the binding

At last I modify the binding expression for the `DataGridTextColum`'s width:

```
Width="{Binding Data.WidthAuthor, Source={StaticResource proxy}....
```

et voilá, it works!

I will continue research on how to do this for the multi-column sort. If I can't find a solution to that I will open a new question. If no one adds a solution for that in the next days, I will accept my own answer.

**UPDATE:** I solved the multi-column sort problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947183/remember-wpf-datagrid-sort-order).