# Remember WPF DataGrid sort order

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661767/binding-properties-width-sorting-of-datagrid-on-dynamic-tabpage).

#### 1. Setup

I have a wpf window that contains a `TabControl` with dynamically created items. The `ItemSource` of this `TabControl` is bound to a list of `Group`s. These groups contain a list of elements that is displayed in a `DataGrid` on the `TabPage`.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestWpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource ="{Binding Groups, ElementName=window, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Group}">
                <TextBlock Padding="2" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="contentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:Group}">
                <DataGrid x:Name="dgElements" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="clmName" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorder="False" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="clmDesc" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorder="False" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

This all works fine.

#### 2. The Question

The `DataGrid` allows **multi-column** sort out of the box. But unfortunatly, if I switch between the tabpages, the sorting is lost.
I want that the *multi-column sorting is maintained for each tabpage/datagrid*.

It is possible to bind the `SortDirection` of `DataGridTextColumn` to a property, but that does not remember the *sort order* of the columns. And debugging I found that when I switch the tabpage, the `SortDirection` is reset *before* the new `ItemSource` is set, so I can't store this.

The question is: **How can I keep the multi-column sort settings per tabpage/datagrid?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After reading a lot of articles only almost solving my problem, I finally found a solution.
I inherited my own class from `DataGrid` and stored the `SortDescriptions` per `ItemSource` in a `Dictionary`:

```
public class SortKeepingDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    // Dictionary to keep SortDescriptions per ItemSource
    private readonly Dictionary<object, List<SortDescription>> m_SortDescriptions =
        new Dictionary<object, List<SortDescription>>();

    protected override void OnSorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        base.OnSorting(eventArgs);
        UpdateSorting();
    }
    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(newValue);
        view.SortDescriptions.Clear();

        // reset SortDescriptions for new ItemSource
        if (m_SortDescriptions.ContainsKey(newValue))
            foreach (SortDescription sortDescription in m_SortDescriptions[newValue])
            {
                view.SortDescriptions.Add(sortDescription);

                // I need to tell the column its SortDirection,
                // otherwise it doesn't draw the triangle adornment
                DataGridColumn column = Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SortMemberPath == sortDescription.PropertyName);
                if (column != null)
                    column.SortDirection = sortDescription.Direction;
            }
    }

    // Store SortDescriptions in dictionary
    private void UpdateSorting()
    {       
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource);
        m_SortDescriptions[ItemsSource] = new List<SortDescription>(view.SortDescriptions);
    }
}
```

So, basically, whenever the user changes the sorting, I call `UpdateSorting` and store the current `SortDescription`s in the per `ItemSource` dictionary.
When the `ItemSource` has changed, I look up the `SortDescription`s and reset them in the correct order.

The tricky part is finding the correct `DataGridColumn` to set its `SortDirection`. This is necessary to draw the triangled adornment. I here rely on the equality of `SortMemberPath` and `PropertyName`. Eventually a more generic approach could be necessary.

In the XAML I replaced the `DataGrid` with my `SortKeepingDataGrid` and now the sorting is stored per tabpage.

Since I could not find any other solution, maybe this will help others too.

Comment: "I need to tell the column its SortDirection, otherwise it doesn't draw the triangle adornment" - this comment helps me understand why the sort arrow disappeared in my DataGrid. Thanks.